# SQL select statement puts data into input field - "name" atribute from input won't transfer data to sql insert statement using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have used an sql select statement to fill in a select field in an html form, now I would like to take the value generated by the select field and insert it into my foreign key column.

I have checked all my field names to make sure they are spelt correctly and double checked my code, I think there might be a problem with the 'escape_string', but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried to use 'intval' but it gives me errors. Line 86 it mentions is the '$result' line.

```
    <?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $category_id        = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['fk_cat_port_id']);

    $project_title   = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['proj_title']);

    $description_brief    = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['des_brief']);

    $description_steps           = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['des_steps']);

    $description_conclusion    = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['des_conclusion']);

    $project_link      = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['proj_link']);

    $project_date      = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['proj_date']);

    $disclaimer     = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['disclaimer_rights']);


//insert into database
$query = "INSERT INTO 
         company_profile (fk_cat_port_id, proj_title, des_brief, des_steps, 
                         des_conclusion, proj_link, proj_date, 
                         disclaimer_rights) 
         VALUES ('$category_id', '$project_title', '$description_brief', 
                  '$description_steps', '$description_conclusion', 
                  '$project_link', '$project_date', '$disclaimer')
                  ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or query_error($query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
 }   
?>


    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fk_cat_port_id">Choose Category:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="fk_cat_port_id" value="">
                <?php

                    $query_cat = "SELECT id_cat_port, port_cat_name 
                                  FROM portfolio_categories 
                                  ORDER BY port_cat_name DESC";

                    $result_cat = $mysqli->query($query_cat);

                     if(!$result_cat)
                     {
                         query_error($query_cat, __LINE__, __FILE__);
                     }

                // Do while loop to create option for each row in the database
                    while ($row_cat = $result_cat->fetch_object())
                    {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row_cat->id_cat_port . '">' . $row_cat->port_cat_name . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

> Unknown column 'fk_cat_port_id' in 'field list' Line:86
>
> > File:/customers/b/f/b/tabithabjorkman.com/httpd.www/admin/pages/portfolio_create.php
>
> INSERT INTO 
>                     company_profile (`fk_cat_port_id`, `proj_title`, `des_brief`, `des_steps`, `des_conclusion`, `proj_link`, `proj_date`,
>   `disclaimer_rights`) 
>                     VALUES ('2', 'test', 'test', 
>                     'test', 'test', 'www.test.rg', '2019-10-21T11:09:43', 'test')

[screenshot of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPow2.png)

Comment: "Unknown column" means exactly what it says.  The database is telling you that the column `fk_cat_port_id` doesn't exist on the table `company_profile`.

Comment: That's what's weird, it's there. I added a screen shot of the table above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank those who took the time to try to answer my question.
After looking over it again and again, I found the answer.
There was an error in the sql query and I had put the wrong table name in the query. The wrong table name was similar enough that it got through my checks.
However, I learned a lot about working with stackoverflow, so no regrets and since I use this platform a lot to get answers to problems, I hope that my mistake here can help someone else to remember to check EVERYTHING and remember that it's worth it to make the extra effort to name your tables, classes, ids, etc. using the naming conventions as a guide.
https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/

Answer (score -1):

your query is correct so check column name in your table.

Comment: I did. Everything matches. I added a screenshot of the table.